# Is There a Way to Tell if the User Has Tapped Anywhere on the Screen?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, touch

In my application I am displaying a tutorial notification upon the screen, and to display the next slide I would like the user to be able to tap anywhere on the screen.

I am displaying the tutorial slides with a `Popup` control.

So is there any sure-fire way to know if there is interaction between the user and the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [Touch.FrameReported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touch.framereported.aspx) event. [Here's the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.input.touch.framereported%28v=vs.95%29) to the Windows Phone doc but I gave the other link as it has example code.